# Intel Iris Xe on Ubuntu 21.04 detects the external monitor but outputs no signal

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, 21.04

I have a Dell Vostro 3400 with Intel Iris Xe Graphics and I can't get my external monitor to work properly. I've installed the driver i915 and Ubuntu detects the monitor, but I get no signal output to my monitor when I try to power it up, my screen just keeps blinking as if the monitor was getting connected and disconnected consecutively.

--- The driver

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A 3 VGA | grep -E "VGA|driver"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:9a49] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

---- xrandr output

xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1366x768+1920+156 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
1366x768      59.80*+
1024x768      59.92
800x600       59.86
640x480       59.38
320x240       59.52
720x480       59.71
640x400       59.95
320x200       58.96
1280x720      59.86
1024x576      59.90
864x486       59.92
720x400       59.55
640x350       59.77
XWAYLAND4 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 670mm x 280mm
1920x1080     59.96*+
1440x1080     59.99
1400x1050     59.98
1280x1024     59.89
1280x960      59.94
1152x864      59.96
1024x768      59.92
800x600       59.86
640x480       59.38
320x240       59.52
1680x1050     59.95
1440x900      59.89
1280x800      59.81
720x480       59.71
640x400       59.95
320x200       58.96
1600x900      59.95
1368x768      59.88
1280x720      59.86
1024x576      59.90
864x486       59.92
720x400       59.55
640x350       59.77

[External monitor is detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeHw7.jpg)

Comment: I have the same problem.